# How to manage NULL values with numeric fields in cursor?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How to manage NULL values in numeric fields returned by cursor in Select stament, to manage efficienly aritmetic operations ?

Comment: I think we need to see more of what you are doing to understand how to help you.  Why are you using a cursor? It is usually a poor practice.

Comment: It is a cursor with a few records, I need to iteract with each record to filter with if, elseif, else conditions to make differents aritmetics operations, otherwise I used several select staments, may be to maney procedures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't use cursors.
2. If you must (really?), you can use the ISNULL function:

   ```
   SELECT ISNULL(fieldname, 0)
   ```

will give you a "0" (zero) instead of NULL.

Answer (score 5):

```
ISNULL(value, replacement)
```

will replace `value` with `replacement` if `value` IS NULL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you cannot avoid a cursor in the first place, I don't understand why a `NULL` would be handled much differently in a variable than you would in a query - there is `INSULL`, `COALESCE`, `CASE WHEN` etc.

One interesting thing:

```
DECLARE @v as int -- initialized to NULL

{ -- loop through a cursor
FETCH NEXT INTO @v
}
```

You won't be able to necessarily distinguish an uninitialized `@v` from when the last row's `@v` setting was `NULL`.